# Switchyard basic authentication

Tags: authentication, jboss

The following authentication policy is defined in login-config.xml

```
<policy>

<!--- - - - -->
  <application-policy name="myAuthenticationPolicy">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="com.ge.trans.mp.samp.jaas.LoggingLdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</module-option>
```

A switchyard configuration is below:

```
<switchyard xmlns="urn:switchyard-config:switchyard:1.0"
                xmlns:sy="urn:switchyard-config:switchyard:1.0"
                xmlns:bean="urn:switchyard-component-bean:config:1.0"
                xmlns:camel="urn:switchyard-component-camel:config:1.0"
                xmlns:http="urn:switchyard-component-http:config:1.0"
                xmlns:sca="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/opencsa/sca/200912">
  <sca:composite name="http-bridge-esb" targetNamespace="urn:switchyard-quickstart:http-binding:1.0">
    <sca:service name="httpPostService" promote="HttpPostBuilder/HttpPost" **sy:security="basic-auth"**>
      <http:binding.http>
        <operationSelector operationName="postMessage"/>
        <http:contextPath>myContextPath</http:contextPath>
      </http:binding.http>
    </sca:service>
    <sca:component name="HttpPostBuilder">
       <camel:implementation.camel>
        <camel:xml path="META-INF/route.xml"/>
      </camel:implementation.camel>
      <sca:service name="HttpPost">
        <sca:interface.java interface="my.post.Class"/>
      </sca:service>
    </sca:component>
  </sca:composite>
  <domain>
    <securities>
      <**security name="basic-auth"** securityDomain="myAuthenticationPolicy" rolesAllowed="mesgPoster"/>
    </securities>
  </domain>
</switchyard>
```

This configuration starts up in JBoss 6.1 EAP and appears to receive messages correctly, however it does not appear to authenticate.

I am presuming that the default username password callback handler is used to handle basic auth, and am also presuming the security domain reference in the security element relates to the application policy name configured in login-config.xml.

I seem unable to locate an example configuration showing basic auth authentication using an LDAP configuration policy.

If someone could point out the dots that I am missing, or somewhere that an example for a switchyard basic auth configuration exists it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I mean http basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Your login-config.xml is incomplete and invalid.

It should look something like this:

```
<application-policy name="myAuthenticationPolicy">
  <authentication>
    <login-module flag="required" code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule">
      <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</module-option>
      <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldap://XXX:389/</module-option>
      <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</module-option>
      <module-option name="bindDN">XXX\XXX</module-option>
      <module-option name="bindCredential">XXX</module-option>
      <module-option name="baseCtxDN">dc=XXX,dc=XXX</module-option>
      <module-option name="baseFilter">(sAMAccountName={0})</module-option>
      <module-option name="rolesCtxDN">dc=XXX,dc=XXX</module-option>
      <module-option name="roleFilter">(member={1})</module-option>
      <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN">true</module-option>
      <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID">name</module-option>
      <module-option name="java.naming.referral">follow</module-option>
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</application-policy>
```